# How to send attachment in chatterbot

Tags: python, bots, chatterbot

I am trying to build a bot using python. I am using chatterbot (
a python package), I am able to send and receive messages according the knowledge which i have built.

But I want to send attachment in the chat response. Attachment may be a pdf of excel file or image.
I've tried for by making custom class for message response and listTrainer also.

Please help to solve this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

[bot chatting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VepyB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `django_chatterbot` app.

currently chatterbot doesn't support this feature over Django. However you could make a work around in urls, views and app.html files to achieve this task.

In [url.py](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/ext/django_chatterbot/urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ChatterBotView


urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^$',
        ChatterBotView.as_view(),
        name='chatterbot',
    ),
    url(r'^test/getFile', 'getFile')
]
```

In [views.py](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/ext/django_chatterbot/views.py)

```
def getFile(request):
    fileContent = "Your name is %s" % request.GET['name']
    res = HttpResponse(fileContent)
    res['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=yourname.txt'
    return res
```

In [app.html](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/django_app/example_app/templates/app.html#L88)

```
if (inputData.text.indexOf("please download this script and run it") !=-1) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {name: 'Jon'};
        $(function(){
            $("body").append('<iframe src="/test/getFile?'+ $.param(data) + '" style="display: none;" ></iframe>');
        });
    </script>
}
```

I hope this information will help you solve your problem.